# Google Chart API - Change value with mouse click (setValue)

Tags: google-visualization, graph-visualization

I have created a donut chart from Google Charts API.  When clicking on each slice, it should increase by 10 units and decrease the adjacent slice (clockwise) by 10 units.  What I have thus far is a alert popup that explains this, but I would like to redraw the chart with the new values.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Option');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
        data.addRows([
          ['Option A',    40],
          ['Option B',    30],
          ['Option C',    30]
        ]);

        // Set chart options
        var options = {
          height: 300,
          fontName: 'Lato, sans-serif',
          title: 'Values per option',
          titleTextStyle: {
            color: '#5a5a5a',
            fontSize: 20,
            bold: true,
            align: 'center'
          },
          pieHole: 0.6,
          slices: {
            0: {color: 'red'},
            1: {color: 'blue'},
            2: {color: 'green'}
          },
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            textStyle: {
              color: '#5a5a5a',
              fontSize: 14
            }
          },

          enableInteractivity: true,
          pieSliceText: 'none'
        };

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        function selectHandler() {
          var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
          if (selectedItem && selectedItem.row <2) {
            var activeTrait = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                activePerc  = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 1);
                activePercNew = parseInt(activePerc)+10
                adjaceTrait = data.getValue(selectedItem.row+1, 0);
                adjacePerc  = data.getValue(selectedItem.row+1, 1);
                adjacePercNew = parseInt(adjacePerc)-10

            alert(activeTrait + ' has a value of ' + activePerc + '%.  The new value will now be set to ' + activePercNew + '% and ' + adjaceTrait + ' will be corrected to ' + adjacePercNew + '%.');
          }

          if (selectedItem && selectedItem.row == 2) {
            var activeTrait = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
                activePerc  = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 1);
                activePercNew = parseInt(activePerc)+10
                adjaceTrait = data.getValue(selectedItem.row-2, 0);
                adjacePerc  = data.getValue(selectedItem.row-2, 1);
                adjacePercNew = parseInt(adjacePerc)-10

            alert(activeTrait + ' has a value of ' + activePerc + '%.  The new value will now be set to ' + activePercNew + '% and ' + adjaceTrait + ' will be corrected to ' + adjacePercNew + '%.');
          }
        }

        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" style="width:800; height:300"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would just like to resize the selected and adjacent slices by clicking on a single slice.  Not sure if I should create a var newdata with the changed values and use chart.draw(newdata, option)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you're pretty much there, and you're definitely on the right track with your answer. You can use data.setValue() to adjust your values then you would have something like this in your second "if" statement:

```
  data.setValue(selectedItem.row,1, activePercNew);
  data.setValue(selectedItem.row-2,1, adjacePercNew);
  chart.draw(data, options);
  // the thing we just clicked on was redrawn so it lost its handler, reinstate it:
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
```

And the same in the first but with selectedItem.row+1 instead of selectedItem.row-2. Or, ideally, tidy that section up a little so the two if statements figure out which things you're referring to and then one bit of code does the redraw. For example, here's an adjusted handler function which also doesn't rely on there being 3 sections:

```
function selectHandler() {
  var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
  var numRows = data.getNumberOfRows();
  // verify the selection isn't inexplicibly invalid
  if (selectedItem && selectedItem.row < numRows && selectedItem.row >= 0) {
    // find the two items we're looking at
    var curItem = selectedItem.row;

    // we either want selected.row + 1 or we want 0 if the selected item was the last one
    var otherItem = selectedItem.row == numRows - 1 ? 0 : selectedItem.row + 1;

    // calculate the new values
    var activePerc  = data.getValue(curItem , 1);
    var activePercNew = parseInt(activePerc)+10;
    var adjacePerc    = data.getValue(otherItem , 1);
    var adjacePercNew = parseInt(adjacePerc  )-10;

    // update the chart
    data.setValue(curItem,1, activePercNew);
    data.setValue(otherItem,1, adjacePercNew);
    chart.draw(data, options);
    // the thing we just clicked on was redrawn so it lost its handler, reinstate it:
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
  }
}
```

You might want to then also consider what should happen if a value is forced right to zero - with this solution it'll disappear from the chart, and then the next click will force an invalid negative value.

Comment: Thank you hevens!  This is exactly what I needed!  Your suggested function works perfectly.  I added an otherItemValue and placed it in an if statement.  If it was 0, then the otherItem should change to numRows - (curItem + otherItem).  This took care of the issue if a slice was forced to zero.  I also stopped the script if the activePerc reached 0.  And placed a reset button.  Thank you again!